# Multiple bars into the same .progress with href is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

progress-bar-danger is not shown, i tried the below html without , it is working. I dont know why it is not working with ? please see the screen shot & suggest.. thanks

```html
<div class="progress">
    <a href="/sample1">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 65%">
            <span>65%</span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="/sample2">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 35%">
            <span>35%</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off: You're placing 2 `<a>` elements and within those, you're placing the bars with a % width.

That's your problem. You need to put the classes of the `<div>` on the parent `<a>` and the span would then be expendable as well.
Like so:

```
<div class="progress">
    <a href="/sample1" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="float:left;width:65%;display:block;">
            <span>65%</span>
    </a>
    <a href="/sample2" class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 35%;float:left;display:block;">
            <span>35%</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Otherwise, the `div`s within the `<a>` will be 65% and 35% of their `parent` width. That's how % widths work. If you want to place elements next to each other using `%`, they will need to be within the same parent container.